# Content type in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller in CodeIgniter which have few functions in it. For ajax interaction, in some functions where i had to return `json` objects, i did the following :

```
$this->output->set_content_type("application/json");
```

The ajax is working fine. But now when i'm trying to echo something from a function and going to that function in browser gives me the following :

```
Content Encoding Error
```

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

I tried setting content type to "text/html", i don't know. Also i tried removing all those content type set. That also didn't help me echoing out of the controller.

What should i do, to echo something out of a specific controller function just in case for testing purposes?

Comment: You seem to have GZIP compression turned on in your config. it might mess with your AJAX transfers and/or caching.

Comment: You were right! Thanks. Why not put that in the answer, so can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have GZIP compression turned on in your config. it might mess with your AJAX transfers and/or caching.

By default you don't need to give a content-type when serving json encoded data. So it's better to leave the whole content-type out to prevent future issues. Besides that it's also handy because there can be occasions where you might have one AJAX call give either a JSON encoded string or just a piece of output.

Good luck!